# using python script, update a table?

Tags: python, vertica

I have multiple Vertica tables. I create a table comprising of columns of these multiple tables.

I need to write a python script such that every time I update those multiple tables, this main table also gets updated.

Something like we do with views, but they take time and my requirement is using python script.

how can I do this?

Comment: so you have a single table containing all the columns in your database ? - why not just create a sister table for all the tables in your(project) and just use merge every time you  load data into your main tables ?

Comment: I don't think the maintenance involved with such a task out weighs the purpose of a view. You're going to create a lot of overhead trying to maintain the "freshness" of the data.